# Is there such thing as a bowl shaped "ceiling bounce" lamp?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, lamp

I'd like a lamp that acts like an IKEA floor lamp but without the long stick. Ideally it's bown shaped to not limit much of the light output to a tiny circle on the ceiling. I'd place a LIFX bulb in it and put it on the top of a cabinet.

[image][image]

Is there a name for this thing? I've been looking at stores and ebay, but can't find anything. They all either have a lampshade, limiting the lumens output by diffusing too much, or have a stand or E14. I'd have no problem creating one on my own, just don't know where to begin.

Comment: I don't think there is a name, but I do know that there are "lamp kits" to put a cord, bulb socket and switch into just about anything. I have a pretty cool go-kart engine lamp. Most of the time it requires very minimal tools and skill. Might be worth a DIY route.

Comment: Such fixtures definitely exist. I have no idea what the industry term for them is; all I can suggest is shopping.